# Sitecore Remote Initial Setup Error: Could not find JSS app configuration

Tags: jss, deployment

I'm following the guide to deploy `jss` components created locally with `Vuejs` into Sitecore.

Everything seems to work except for the deployment part.

The following is my setup file:

```
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "",
    "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "deploySecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "deployUrl": "https:myazure.net/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "localhost:3000"
  }
}
```

The website loads locally on `http://localhost:3000`.

And I'm getting the following error:

> Unexpected response from import service:
>   Status message: Bad Request
>   Body: Could not find JSS app configuration for 'myapp'. Ensure you have included or previously installed a configuration patch file for the JSS app. Running 'jss deploy config' may resolve this.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: running on Azure? have you done this https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/azure-deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 'jss deploy config' step you need a path to the Sitecore webroot, the instancePath in the scjssconfig. for Example

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sc911.sc",
```

When running local this works, for remote or running on Azure you need to do somethings.

When in Azure, the config deployment step must be performed manually (in production, it should be performed by an automated build step). For our purposes, we can use our FTPS client to deploy the JSS app's

> /sitecore/config/*

files to the Azure website's 
 `/site/wwwroot/app_config/include` directory.

This config file contains your:

```
 <javaScriptServices>
      <apps>
         <app name="myapp"
```

See the documentation about [JSS Azure deployments](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/azure-deployment)

Comment: Thanks! This worked :)